# Jquery Dynamic Form not displaying Image

Tags: jquery

I have a form and I dynamically add another form at the end of the first form when a Button is clicked. 
I have an image on the 2nd form that isn’t displaying (browser default image)

```
$("#addNew").on("click", function () {
    $('#form1Div').append('<form id="newAddForm" name="newAddForm"></form>'); //append a new form element with id newAddForm
    $('#newAddForm').attr("action", "").attr("method", "post") //set the form attributes
    //add in all the needed input elements
    .append('<p></p>')
        .append('<p id="addNewBanner" class="addNewBannerStyle">Add New</p>')
        .append('<p id="addNewBanner1">You are about to add a new Account Number and its NEW Address</p>')
        .append('<p class="pTxtFields"><label for="newAccount">Account Number </label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="newAccount" id="newAccount" value="New Account Number" class="inputNumTextBox1 keyup-numeric" maxlength="10">' +
        '<span id="acctSpan" class="errorStyle">XXXX<span></p>')
        .append('<p id="addNewBanner"></p>')
        .append('<p class="pTxtFields"><label for="newNEWAddress">NEW Address &nbsp</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="inputNumTextBox1" name="newNEWAddress" id="newNEWAddress" value="New Address"></p>')
        .append('<p id="addNewBanner2"></p>')
        .append('<div id="addNewFormButtons"><ul class="addXXX"><li id="saveBtn" name="saveBtn" value="Save" onclick="doUpdate(this.form)">Save</li>')
        .append('<li id="canBtn" name="canBtn" value="Cancel" onclick="doCancel(this.form)">Cancel</li>')
        .append('<li><img id="plusSignLogo" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo_u94.png" alt="DUH !"/></li><li>Add More</li><ul>')
        .append('<p id="addNewFormErr"></p></div>');

});
```

Comment: Any relevant HTML/CSS would be helpful.

Comment: Is the path correct? And is `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` being parsed into a real path or showing up in the result?

Comment: That’s my problem the context isn’t a real path.  I added <script>var ctx = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"</script> But how do I add the variable to the SRC element? 
src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo_u94.png" I’m guessing escape characters ?